# Retaining uploaded file after posting the submit form

Tags: php, html, upload

I am looking for a solution where I want to retain the uploaded files even after a submit button is clicked. In my case I am planning to give a choice for the user that when the user feels that one of the uploaded file is not of his choice even after post submit, he can reupload only that file which he wants to replace and not requiring to reupload the other files. Is there a way how this can be done using HTML, PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Are you keeping a record of the files uploaded in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the file has been uploaded use `move_uploaded_file` to move it to a temporary location (don't just leave it in the systems tmp directory in case it get's automatically cleaned up).

When the form has been submitted you can then move it from the temporary location to a permanent one using `rename`.

Then write a script that runs every X hours that goes through files in your temporary location that are older than a certain time period (`filemtime`) and delete them (`unlink`) to clean up any files that were uploaded but the form was not submitted.

Comment: hi fire, thanks for your answer, is it possible to get an example code. Need not be working, code os much more better to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-populate a file upload field for security reasons.

An example of how this could lead to malicious behavior is you could have a hidden file upload, where you populate it with any file you wish from the users hard drive.

The only way you could potentially retain the selected file is to submit the form data via AJAX so the user never actually leaves the page, and only redirect the user to a thankyou page (for example) when the validation has succeeded.